# How do I code a DataTable.RowChanged event to be attached at compile time?

Tags: c#, events, datatable

I have the following setup in a Windows Forms project:

`myDataGridView`, whose data source is `myBindingSource`, whose data source is `myProjectDataSet` and whose data member is `myDataTable`, whose data is populated from a database at runtime per user request.

When the user makes a data change on `myDataGridView` I have the changes filtering down to update `myDataTable` as well. I then want to handle `myDataTable`'s `RowChanged` event, but I'm not quite sure in which project file I should put the code to attach the event handler and then handle the event so that they are hooked up when the data table is "initialized". I know I can hook up the event in my Form.cs file after the form loads, but I'd prefer to hook it up in `myProjectDataSet.cs` if I can. But, since `myProjectDataSet.cs` is auto-generated, I'm not sure if this is the best place to do it.

I hope that made sense. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Could you explain why you would perfer to hook it to myProjectDataset. Also could you give a few code snipets.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, realized I had to add to hook it up in my Form.Designer.cs file after `myProjectDataSet` instantiated.

```
this.myProjectDataSet.myDataTable.RowChanged += new System.Data.DataRowChangeEventHandler(myDataTable_RowChanged);
```

Then, of course, I handled the event in Form.cs

```
private void myDataTable_RowChanged(object sender, System.Data.DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    //Do stuff.
}
```

But now the hook is getting wiped out when Form.Designer.cs auto-generates. Oh well I'll figure that one out too.